# Javascript won't href to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

This might sound like a stupid question, but that's because it is. Is there a reason this won't actually href to the page? I click it and literally nothing happens.

```
window.location.href = "http://theromdepot.com/roms/report.php?file=" + window.location.pathname + "/" + document.getElementById('title').innerHTML + "&issue=" + issue;
```

I actually made another website that functions essentially the same way and it works perfectly fine. This code is for something else, but it's essentially sending the information the same way:

```
window.location.href = "rename.php?originalname=" + originalname + "&newname=" + newname;
```

There's something strange going on because I actually copied and pasted code from the other website that does work and I had the same issue. I click the button and nothing happens. I put an alert before and after the href to make sure the function was being called and it is, just no page change. Not sure if PHP is involved in any way. Can anybody tell me what's going on here?

Here's the full page: http://pastebin.com/zHfHcYmV

Here's the website just in case: http://theromdepot.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your page, this line of code:

```
window.location.href = "http://theromdepot.com/roms/report.php?file=" + window.location.pathname + "/" + document.getElementById('title').innerHTML + "&issue=" + issue
```

throws this error and thus does not successfully execute:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

This is presumably because `document.getElementById('title')` returns `null` because there is no element in your HTML with `id="title"`.

Comment: Wow, I really should have looked harder for that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Syllith - yes.  Always look in the error or debug log anytime something isn't working as expected.   Your first clue is often there.